# componentDidMount can't receive props from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Assume a parent-component "A" and a child-component "B". Component "A" makes an Ajax call.

I can't get props value passed from "A" to "B"'s `componentDidUpdate`, why is it so?

Basicailly I want to do a on scroll detection event like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    $('#container').on('scroll', function() {
        if(Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) === $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            if(this.props.items.length < this.props.itemTotal) {
                fetchItems(this.props.items.length)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

`this.props.items.length` is not defined? I can get the value of `nextProps.items` in `componentWillRecieveProps` method?

Comment: Use es6 arrow function  instead of `function` `$('#container').on('scroll', ()=> {})`

Comment: @Ved that would mess up with `$(this).scrollTop()`

Answer (score 3):

Inside your `scroll` event handler function, `this` is referring to `#container` element. You can store a reference to the component before going inside the handler.

```js
componentDidMount() {
    var thisComponent = this;
    $('#container').on('scroll', function() {
        if(Math.ceil($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).height()) === $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            if(thisComponent.props.items.length < thisComponent.props.itemTotal) {
                fetchItems(thisComponent.props.items.length)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: nope, #container is just a element in my componentB

Comment: Yeah but jQuery overrides `this` inside the handler and makes it point to the events invocation-element, in your case `#container`. Just try it out for yourself.

Comment: I see. I'm able to make it work using setTimeout, in your opinion which one is the better solution? I don't understand your solution, how can store a reference solve the problem? I thought the problem is componentDidMount render too early before this.props.item receive any value?